# Check for Android TV box

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to differentiate between Android smartphones, tablets and TV box.
Is there any way to check that on which device type app is running ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use following method to detect type of device :

1. Add a bool in dimension's files to detect Tablet :

Add this line in sw720dp/dimens.xml & sw600dp/dimens.xml

```
<bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
```

And in values/dimens.xml. make it false :

```
<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
```

2. Add this method, and use booleans to detect type :

   ```
   boolean isTablet;
   boolean isAndroidTv;

   isTablet = (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
   if (!isTablet) {
       isTablet = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
   }

   UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) (context.getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE));
   if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
       isAndroidTv = true;

   } else if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEVISION) || context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK)) {
       isAndroidTv = true;
   } else if (!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.touchscreen")) {
       isAndroidTv = true;
   } else if (!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.telephony")) {
       isAndroidTv = true;
   }
   ```

Comment: If isAndroidTv is false and isTablet is false, then device is mobile